# I want to resize or scale the div on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, resize, scale

Can any one help me, i already checked resizing demo but this work through handles but i need on hover and when div scale then other content automatically go below
like this link http://sea-hunters.com/ in this link right side menu have effect on hover?

Comment: Post relevant code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize using the jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

```
$('ul li').hover(function(){
  $(this).animate(... //animate height and width
}, function(){
  $(this).animate(... //animate back
});
```

Comment: Hi check my below code, i want to move text on hover , that function work for me , but problem is that in my menu i have different sizes of text that why margin left not suitable for me, i m not good in english but i just want when hover text then align right and when hover out then move left, check the below code

Comment: $(function() {
  var timer;
$("#effect").mouseover(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(      function() {
    $( "#effect" ).animate({ 
     marginLeft: "80px"
    }, 200 );
   }, 50); 
}).mouseout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);  
});

 });

$(function() {
  $( "#effect" ).hover(
   function() {
    $( "#effect" ).animate({    
    marginLeft: "0px"
    }, 200 );
   }
  );
 });